# SSIS: How to filter rows with 1 or more null columns and identify which are the columns?

Tags: mysql, ssis

I hope someone can help me with this. I am doing an extraction from excel and load into ole database using SSIS. Before, it enters the database, I have to filter out rows with invalid and null columns and store these rows with errors in another database for errors.

This is the data in my TransactionRecord Excel:

```
CustID  TransactionDate TransactionTime AmountSpent
123     1/2/2011        10:30           $1 
(null)  3/4/2012       (null)           $8 
789     3/4/2011        12:00           $7 
698     (null)          11:23           $5
```

*(null) represents empty fields in excel.

Currently, this is what I have done in SSIS

TransactionRecord.xlsx ---> Conditional Split --(Case 1:filter rows with null)--> ErrorDB

                                                                      --(default output)---> TransactionDB

I am only able to filter out rows with null values with this condition: 

ISNULL(CustID) || ISNULL(TransactionDate) || ISNULL(TransactionTime) || ISNULL(AmountSpent)

However, with this method, I am unable to identify which are the columns with null values. I am thinking of having a ErrorMsg column in ErrorDB which will state which are the columns that needed to be changed.

ErrorDB:

```
CustID  TransactionDate   TransactionTime   AmountSpent   ErrorMsg
null    3/4/2012          null              $8            CustIDNull, TimeNull
698     null              11:23             $5            DateNull
```

I have tried to used "Derived Column" transformation to add a new ErrorMsg column, however, I am unable to pinpoint which columns have the errors.

Is there any better way of extracting out these error columns and store them in a database?

(can't post image as I am new to stackoverflow, thus do not have enough reputation points)

Comment: Once the bad records are loaded into your ErrorDB table, you can use MySQL's [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) operator: `SELECT * FROM ErrorDB WHERE CustID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your ErrorMsg column to contain the first column error found then add the following to your derived column:

```
ISNULL(CustID) ? "CustID Error" : 
  ISNULL(TransactionDate) ? "TransactionDate Error" :
    ISNULL(TransactionTime) ? "TransactionTime Error" : 
      ISNULL(AmountSpent) ? "AmountSpent Error" : "Unknown Error"
```

If you want to have a list of column errors then use something like this:

```
LTRIM((ISNULL(CustID) ? "CustID " : "") +
(ISNULL(TransactionDate) ? "TransactionDate " : "") +
(ISNULL(TransactionTime) ? "TransactionTime " : "") +
(ISNULL(AmountSpent) ? "AmountSpent" : ""))
```

Alternatively send your errors through a script component transformation, you could then set it write out one row for every error column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a multicast transformation to break off from your main dataflow
2. Use an asynchronous script component to loop through all columns and write a new row for each row/column that has a null value
3. Write the resulting dataflow to your ErrorDB

Code for this script would go something like:

```
' Loop through all columns and create field elements
For Each column As IDTSInputColumn100 In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection

'Get Column Name
sColumnName = column.Name

' Get column value, will catch if null 
Try

    'Clean up column name (VB/SSIS will do this when processing columns so we need to ask for the value using cleaned up column name)
    sColumnNameClean = column.Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("-", "")

    'Get column value
    sColValue = rowType.GetProperty(sColumnNameClean).GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString()


Catch

    'Add reference to function to create row here, referencing sColumnName

End Try


Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your data to create an Excel 2010 file.

Then I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [123XLSX] (
    [CustID] INT  NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] datetime NOT NULL,
    [TransactionTime] datetime NOT NULL,
    [AmountSpent] money NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [123XLSXError] (
    [CustID] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [TransactionDate]  VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [TransactionTime]  VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [AmountSpent]  VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] int,
    [ErrorColumn] int
)
```

Now, connect your Excel source to OleDB Dest (Table 123XLSX]. From this destination, send the Error Output to another OLEDB Dest (Table 123XLSXError).

The result:

```
  SELECT * FROM [dbo].[123XLSX]
  SELECT * FROM [dbo].[123XLSXError]

CustID TransactionDate         TransactionTime         AmountSpent
------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
123    2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 10:30:00.000 1.00
789    2011-03-04 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 12:00:00.000 7.00

CustID TransactionDate          TransactionTime         AmountSpent ErrorCode  ErrorColumn
------------------------------  -----------             ----------- ----------
NULL   2012-03-04 00:00:00      NULL                     8           -1071607683 41
698    NULL                     1899-12-30 11:23:00      5           -1071607683 42
```

Although this is not the exact solution, it gives you the rows that errored along with their field values.

If your want to further polish this result, here are a few good examples. If you need help, please let us know.

https://naseermuhammed.wordpress.com/tips-tricks/getting-error-column-name-in-ssis/

http://dougbert.com/blog/post/Adding-the-error-column-name-to-an-error-output.aspx